# calling function as argument, is this bad practice?

Tags: php, function

```
$myVar=myFunction(array_reverse(explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])));
```

Anything wrong with nesting functions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ok as long as you can *guarantee that each function will always return the desired type*. For instance if a function might return a FALSE value, it may be cast to an unexpected value.

The example provided works because both `explode` (as called) and `array_reverse` will both always return an array.

A counter-example:

```
mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(...), 'INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ....');
```

Since `mysqli_connect` may return a resource OR `FALSE` it shouldn't be chained like this. The return value should always be checked for correctness.

Comment: chosen from amongst the other very good answers for making the point about the validity of the return value.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally valid to do this, but keep it readable. If you nest 15 function calls or nest a handful of function callss with several parameters each, you'll have an intensely unfun debugging experience.

Answer (score 1):

No it is perectly valid to do that

Comment: I'd add that one downside is that it makes it harder to read, and therefore to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bad practice because it makes the code harder to understand and therefore to maintain.
A good practice to overcome this problem is to comment your code (heavily).

Answer (score 0):

People nest functions like that all of the time.  Functions are meant to be used in this way.  Since functions can return a value, it is, therefore, meaningful to assign a variable to a function, to get the value of that function into a PHP variable.

Thank god for functions returning values, otherwise, it would be a mess to think of it the other way...